# Add cell to number edition

Tags: google-sheets

Trying to make the products bought line up to the right edition number based on their SKUs and order in the sheet.

Right now, some emails don't show up (whether repeated in the purchase or almost randomly).

(The real data sheet has over 1000 purchases and 720 SKUs)

Comment: EXAMPLE SHEET - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sce5uDQe0liqNZIAeWcXvOqUTqOjK8v_KtGZKr6qTp8/edit#gid=709263740

Comment: Rows 21 and 22 of the sheet `Tab01` are missing key data in Columns B and D (as well as C). Those pieces of data would be used to group items together. If the omissions in those rows and columns are intentional, please explain in detail what should happen in such cases where Vendor and Name are missing; if it is an error in the sample data, please fill the missing information and report back. I believe I can solve this in one formula, but I need all the information to be accurate and understood going in.

Comment: Also, why do you have Vendor-Name-SKU listings in your `TabDesired` sheet which do not exist at all in `Tab01` (and which therefore have no emails listed for them), e.g., Vendor1 Name1 lep-1-1-1-8x10

Comment: I've had this post open and your spreadsheet saved to my Drive for 17 hours. I like to keep my Drive clean. If you're still interested in my sharing a solution, please answer the above questions by EOD. Otherwise, I'll assume you are all set and will close the browser window hosting your post and delete your spreadsheet from my Drive.

Comment: Thank you for helping, I ended up using CONCATENATE for the order numbers and emails and that fixed the issue

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(SPLIT(VLOOKUP(C2:C, TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(
 {'Tab02'!B2:B, 'Tab02'!A2:A&",", 'Tab02'!B2:B&"×"}, 
 "select max(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col3"),,9^9)), 
 "×")), 2, 0), ",")))
```

[image]

Comment: it won't show emails used for multiple purchases for the same SKU (it won't show an email that was used to purchase the same piece twice (ex email1 with lep-1-2-1-8x10)

Comment: @Spacey Indeed it won't. But it was free! :)

Answer (score 0):

This formula in cell D1 on a tab called MK.Idea might work for you if i understand the question?  It only needs Tab01 to work.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT({"Emails-->";VLOOKUP(C2:C,TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY('Tab01'!A:C&{"|","",""},"select MAX(Col3) group by Col3 pivot Col1"),,9^9)),"|")),2,0)}," ")))
```

Comment: it won't show emails used for multiple purchases for the same SKU (it won't show an email that was used to purchase the same piece twice (ex email1 with lep-1-2-1-8x10)

Comment: @Spacey Indeed it won't. But it was free! :)